# how to make x-frame-bypass in vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js, iframe, vuejs2, x-frame-options

I'm trying to open a website that should show me a table.
The website is running on this url: "https://:16311/ibm/console//webtop/eventviewer/eventViewer.jsp".

My application is running on another server at url: "https://:5000/bsm".
I am try to open the table by using  like this:

```
    <div>
      <iframe src="https://<ip address>:16311/ibm/console//webtop/eventviewer/eventViewer.jsp"></iframe>
    </div>
```

then i got the erro that the request t open the table block because "x-frame-bypass"
i tried those following solution:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-frame-bypass

[How Can I Bypass the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN HTTP Header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783095/how-can-i-bypass-the-x-frame-options-sameorigin-http-header)

[Implement npm package custom component VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770375/implement-npm-package-custom-component-vuejs)

but all those attemps was failed.
how can i open page application inside a iframe?

Comment: `x-frame-bypass` works by proxying your requests via an external server, so even if you got it working all your data would be passed via a third party service which you probably doesn't want. But since you are connecting to this via an IP I'm guessing that this is an internal service on your company network or similar that isn't available to those services anyway. So your best bet here would be to disable the `X-Frame-Options` header in webtop (if possible) or to add your own internal proxy to fetch this via.

Comment: hey,thank you for the explnation i wil try to check if it possible to disable the x-frame